# Is it possible to create nested headers using the display:table tag?

Tags: jsp, displaytag

**Is it possible to nest headers using the `<display:table>` tag library?**

... by which I mean something like the following:

[image]

**Note:** Please let me know if this is not possible within HTML at all?  -- I assume I can at least hack something resembling this structure using plain HTML/JSP tags.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. Please take a look at this [JIRA issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/DISPL-242) for workaround.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  This is great.  Thanks.